# 14.04 doesnt have package imagemagick

Tags: 14.04, imagemagick

Usually I had installed Image Magick on my Ubuntu systems with a command like this

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

or like this:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-imagick
```

Right now I am running the latest 14.04, and those packages seem to have disappeared from the repositories. Am I missing something? Have they been obsoleted? How could I install ImageMagick now?

Comment: you can use this code: https://gist.github.com/rodleviton/74e22e952bd6e7e5bee1 don't forget to read my comment under the code, you should change the path of download.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The package you are looking for is `imagemagick`. Confirm that you have all sources check marked in "Software and Updates":

[image: software and updates package sources]

and then update the package list by opening a terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and then typing the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and enter you password and then

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick php5-imagick
```

and then press <kbd>Return</kbd> to confirm the installation.

Answer (score 8):

In Ubuntu 14.04, `imagemagick` is available on main repository & `php5-imagick` is available on universe repository. So follow command in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository main
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install imagemagick php5-imagick
```

Comment: Just FYI, on Amazon EC2 Ubuntu 14.04 (at least N.Virginia region), `universe` repository is enabled by default. Check `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Answer (score 2):

this did the trick for me...

```
sudo apt-get install php5-imagick
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install imagemagick php-imagick
```

and also had to restart apache before it started working:

```
systemctl restart apache2
```