# ImageMagick cannot insatll

Tags: 16.04, package-management, software-installation, imagemagick

My Ubuntu doesn't have ImageMagick. I tried to install it from terminal as the instruction in [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471045/14-04-doesnt-have-package-imagemagick). But it gives me error when I input command `sudo apt-get install imagemagick php5-imagick`. The error is

```
xinru@xinru-Alienware-13-R2:~$ sudo apt-get install imagemagick php5-imagick
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php5-imagick is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php5-imagick' has no installation candidate
```

Anyone can help me with this problem, please. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ubuntu 16.04, the default PHP version is 7.x. Package `php5-imagick` is for PHP version 5.x. The correct package is `php-imagick`. So you have to:

```
sudo apt install imagemagick php-imagick
```